# Display name not updating Email.Content_URI

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to update Display name and email id of an existing contact, I am able to update email address, but display name not updating, the code I am using is here. I have tried plenty of more code but nothing is working for me please help.

```
Cursor cursorEmail = getContentResolver()
                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = "
                                + model.getContactid(),
                        null, null);

    if (cursorEmail
            .moveToFirst()) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newUpdate(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                + "=? AND "
                                + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                + "=?",
                        new String[] {
                                String.valueOf(model
                                        .getContactid()),
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                        txtEditedMailId
                                .getText()

                                .toString()
                                .trim()
                                .toLowerCase())
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        txtEditedName
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .trim()
                                .toLowerCase())
                .build());
    }
    cursorEmail.close();

    getContentResolver()
            .applyBatch(
                    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                    ops);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

Cursor cursorEmail = getContentResolver()
        .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                        + " = "
                        + model.getContactid(),
                null, null);

if (cursorEmail.moveToFirst()) {

  //Update Email 

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(
                    Email.CONTACT_ID
                            + "=? AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                            + "=?",
                    new String[] {
                            String.valueOf(model
                                    .getContactid()),
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE })
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                    txtEditedMailId
                            .getText()

                            .toString()
                            .trim()
                            .toLowerCase())

            .build());

     //Update image 

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
            .decodeFile(localPathEditedImage,
                    options);

    Logger.debug("path--------"
            + imgAbsPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
            baos); // bm is the bitmap object
    byte[] photoByteArray = baos
            .toByteArray();

    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

    builder = ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                    + "=?"
                    + " AND "
                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                    + "=?",
            new String[] {
                    String.valueOf(model
                            .getContactid()),
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
    builder.withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,
            photoByteArray);
    ops.add(builder.build());

      //Update Display name 

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newUpdate(
                    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)

            .withSelection(
                    Email.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(model
                            .getContactid()) })

            .withValue(
                    RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                    txtEditedName.getText()
                            .toString())

            .build());

}
cursorEmail.close();

//Execute Batch

getContentResolver().applyBatch(
        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);


//Contact updated
```